# How to add dummy columns based on individuals and then add all to regression?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm looking to add dummy variables for every value of player ID within my current dataframe.

Here is my initial data (there are thousands of observations and hundreds of players):

```
Player ID.           Hits 
Hank Aaron           3
Babe Ruth            2 
Ted Williams         0  
Hank Aaron           4
```

To become this:

```
Player ID           Hits     HankAaronDummy   BabeRuthDummy      Ted WilliamsDummy
Hank Aaron           3            1               0                0
Babe Ruth            2            0               1                0
Ted Williams         0            0               0                1
Hank Aaron           4            1               0                0
```

From that, I need to create new columns for each player that multiply the hits column by the dummy column.

```
Player ID           Hits     HankAaronDummy   HankAaronHits   BabeRuthDummy  BabeRuthHits
Hank Aaron           3            1               3               0              0
Babe Ruth            2            0               0               1              2
Ted Williams         0            0               0               0              0
Hank Aaron           4            1               4               0              0
```

The thing that may complicate this step is that I have a player named "0_Base," who I do not want to create any dummies for. I want to intentionally leave out their dummies and their hits column.

From that I need to be able to add all of the PlayerHits variables into a linear regression model. I have hundreds of pLayers in the data set, so I'm wondering if it's possible to do this automatically.

```
model1 <- lm(Y ~  control1 + control2 + PlayerID + HankAaronHits + BabeRuthHits + TedWilliamsHits ..., data = baseballplayers)
```

I hope my explanation makes sense. This econometric approach is really an alternative to interacting Hits on Player Name, and prevents degrees of freedom issues. In STATA this would be relatively simple, but I'm not amazing with R.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not every observation is uniquely identified by the player id. That is, each player can (and does) appear multiple times in the data set.

Comment: If you need to create dummy columns `cbind(df1, model.matrix(~df1$PlayerID -1))`

Comment: @akrun fixed the issue in the table that you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to create the dummy columns with `model.matrix`, although it is not really needed if we are using the `lm`.  According to `?model.frame`

> If this is an object of fitted-model class such as "lm", the method will either return the saved model frame used when fitting the model (if any, often selected by argument model = TRUE) or pass the call used when fitting on to the default method.

> 

model, x, y, qr
logicals. - If TRUE the corresponding components of the fit (the model frame, the model matrix, the response, the QR decomposition) are returned.

e.g. if we specify `x = TRUE`, it returns the dummy columns for the factor variable

```
model1 <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ ., iris, x = TRUE)
model1$x
```

---

Dummy columns for the factor variables can be created with `model.matrix`

```
m1 <- model.matrix(~factor(df1$PlayerID, levels = unique(df1$PlayerID)) -1)
 colnames(m1) <- paste0(unique(df1$PlayerID), "Dummy")


m2 <- sapply(unique(df1$PlayerID), function(x)  (df1$PlayerID == x) * df1$Hits)
colnames(m1) <- paste0(unique(df1$PlayerID), "Hits")   

out3 <- cbind(df1, m1, m2)
out3
#      PlayerID Hits Hank AaronHits Babe RuthHits Ted WilliamsHits Hank Aaron Babe Ruth Ted Williams
#1   Hank Aaron    3              1             0                0          3         0            0
#2    Babe Ruth    2              0             1                0          0         2            0
#3 Ted Williams    0              0             0                1          0         0            0
#4   Hank Aaron    4              1             0                0          4         0            0


out4$EPA <- EPA
lm(EPA ~ ., data = out4)
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
out1 <- df1 %>%
              mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
              pivot_wider(names_from = PlayerID, values_from = Hits, 
                    values_fill = list(Hits = 0)) %>%
              select(-rn) %>%
              rename_all(~ str_c(., "Hits"))
out2 <-  df1 %>% 
             mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
             pivot_wider(names_from = PlayerID, values_from = Hits, 
               values_fill = list(Hits = 0), values_fn = list(Hits = length)) %>%
             select(-rn) %>%
             rename_all(~ str_c(., "Dummy"))

out3 <- bind_cols(df1, out1, out2)
out3
#PlayerID Hits Hank AaronHits Babe RuthHits Ted WilliamsHits Hank AaronDummy Babe RuthDummy Ted WilliamsDummy
#1   Hank Aaron    3              3             0                0               1              0                 0
#2    Babe Ruth    2              0             2                0               0              1                 0
#3 Ted Williams    0              0             0                0               0              0                 1
#4   Hank Aaron    4              4             0                0               1              0                 0


 out4 <- cbind(out3, EPA = EPA)
 lm(EPA ~ ., data = out4)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(PlayerID = c("Hank Aaron", "Babe Ruth", "Ted Williams", 
"Hank Aaron"), Hits = c(3L, 2L, 0L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: I tried the model matrix commands, but when I input ``` m2 <- m1 * df1$Hits[col(m1)] ``` I get:

"Error in m1 * df1$Hits[col(m1)] : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator"

Comment: @rogues77 Can you check the `class(df1$Hits)` I assumed it as `numeric`

Comment: Ah of course. It was a character. Now that I have created m1 and m2, how do I add them into the regression? Is it simply:
```
model1 <- lm(Y ~  control1 + control2 + PlayerID + m1 + m2 ..., data = baseballplayers)
```

Comment: @rogues77 It should be numeric for Hits.  to do the multiplication.  Please check the data I showed in my post

Comment: I made Hits numeric and it works--thank you. As far as adding the PlayerHits variables into the regression, I am a bit confused. How do I add all those variables to the regression simultaneously?

Comment: @rogues77 what is your `lm` depdenent variable

Comment: The independent variable is "EPA", the dependent variables are PlayerID and the playerhits variables

Comment: @rogues77 assuming you have a vector of 'EPA', then `cbind` it with `out3` and just do `lm(EPA ~., data = out4)`

Comment: I did the model.matrix method you laid out, so I don't have out3

Comment: Is it possible to run the regression using m1 and m2 created in the model.matrix method?

Comment: @rogues77 yes, updated the method.  The `m2` is updated with `sapply` instead of `model.matrix` as I find a mistake

Comment: I managed to get through creating out3, but I can't seem to progress from there. When I try this command
```out4 <- cbind(out3, EPA = EPA)```
I get the error "Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : object 'EPA' not found"

Sorry I'm just a bit lost

Comment: @rogues77 if you check the initial dataset showed, there are only two columns 'PlayerID' and 'Hits'. I assume that you have another column or a vector 'EPA'

Comment: @rogues77 `EPA` is dependent variable and it is not clear from the example, how you are creating it or is it already in the dataset

Comment: Ah I see--I had ```EPA``` in the baeball players dataframe, I just didn't include it in my description of the data, my mistake. So the command ```out4 <- cbind(out3, EPA = EPA)``` was superfluous. I am now trying the regression ```lm(EPA ~ ., data = out3)``` but I get the error "Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels"

Comment: @rogues77 that seems to a different error with respect to the levels

Answer (score 0):

Assume `baseballplayers` as shown reproducibly in the Note at the end in order to make it possible to run the code shown below.

Make sure that `0_Base` is the first level of `Player` to ensure that it is assigned to the reference level.  In that case it won't appear in the model matrix when using the default treatment contrasts.  (The default order when converted to factor is sorted order if Players is character.) Here `*` specifies interactions between Player and Hits as well as the corresponding main effects.  If you also wanted to eliminate Hits add `- Hits` to the formula (however, normally all main effects are included with their interactions so this would be unusual).

```
model1 <- lm(Y ~ Player * Hits + control1 + control2, ballplayers)
```

The following displays the model matrix used by the regression should you wish to check that it is doing what you think.  Note that 0_Base is not included in the model matrix columns.

```
model.matrix(model1)
```

giving:

```
  (Intercept) PlayerBabe Ruth PlayerHank Aaron PlayerTed Williams Hits control1 control2 PlayerBabe Ruth:Hits PlayerHank Aaron:Hits PlayerTed Williams:Hits
1           1               0                1                  0    3        1        1                    0                     3                       0
2           1               1                0                  0    2        4        8                    2                     0                       0
3           1               0                0                  1    0        9       27                    0                     0                       0
4           1               0                1                  0    4       16       64                    0                     4                       0
5           1               0                0                  0    0       25      125                    0                     0                       0
```

### Note

```
baseballplayers <- 
structure(list(Y = 1:5, Player = c("Hank Aaron", "Babe Ruth", 
"Ted Williams", "Hank Aaron", "0_Base"), Hits = c(3, 2, 0, 4, 
0), control1 = c(1, 4, 9, 16, 25), control2 = c(1, 8, 27, 64, 
125)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))


baseballplayers
##   Y       Player Hits control1 control2
## 1 1   Hank Aaron    3        1        1
## 2 2    Babe Ruth    2        4        8
## 3 3 Ted Williams    0        9       27
## 4 4   Hank Aaron    4       16       64
## 5 5       0_Base    0       25      125
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your response . Am I correct in my understanding that the ```subset``` command eliminates the "0-Base" observations from the data set? If so, that's not what I'm looking to do--I'm looking to keep those in the data set, just not generate the dummy variable columns and hits column for those specific observations. Do you know if that's possible?

Comment: OK. I have modified the solution to keep all rows.and ensure that 0_Base is not in any column.